# What's the correct way to pass a cursor to a user defined function?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to pass a cursor to a function like this:

```
.create-or-alter function GetLatestValues(cursor:string) { 
    Logs | where cursor_after(cursor)
}
```

But I get a `Error cursor_after(): argument #1 is invalid` response. Is there something I'm missing? Is string the wrong data type to use?

This approach works properly for lambda functions:

```
let GetLatestValues = (cursor:string) {
   Logs | where cursor_after(cursor)
};
GetLatestValues('') | take 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, defining a function in Kusto validates stored function, and in case you're using cursor the system will attempt to do it with empty parameter, leading to failure.
You can override this behavior using skipvalidation=true parameter (see docs at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/functions#create-function)

```
.create-or-alter function with (skipvalidation = "true")
GetLatestValues(cursor:string)
{ 
    Logs | where cursor_after(cursor)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what it needed.